# Firebase Cloud Messaging: how to upload APNs authentication key?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios

In the official [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key) it says that we need go to the Project settings and in Cloud Messaging Tab add APNs authentication key. However, when I go to the Cloud Messaging tab I see only Web Push Certificates, there is no possibility to upload APNs authentication key for IOS app there. How to upload this key to Firebase project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, I didn't have correct permission in Firebase console, once I got `owner permission`, I was able to see upload UI for `APN` key.